# file_get_contents() cannot work with HTTPS

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https, file-get-contents

I created a plugin for my wordpress website. This plugin use file_get_contents() PHP function to get contents from my other websites. Everything goes well in local host (XAMPP). But when I run the plugin in my server which has HTTPS installed, it does not work anymore. Please note that the websites (I need to scrape the contents from) don't install HTTPS.

I searched for many solutions here (such as edit in php.ini: *extension=php_openssl.dll*  and  *allow_url_fopen = On* ) but it still doesn't work.

Thanks for reading and Helps!

Comment: Look into CORS, using the built in dev tools in my browser helped when I was transitioning into HTTPS.
<https://stackoverflow.com/a/52450559/9559879> <--Here I had to work with allowing remote resources when my setup wasn't allowing loading from insecure sources, regardless of my server side set up, as far as I was aware. Then I realized I slept through the development of security in the browser. Just kept things updated regardless of changlogs lol.

Comment: *"...it does not work anymore..."* - this is the only but unfortunately unusable problem description. Please describe clearly what exactly you did, what you expected to happen, what happened instead, the full error messages you get, errors you might get in the browsers console output, errors you might get a the webserver... Just says that it *"does not work"* does not provide sufficient information to help you.